# java Binary Search Tree inorder recursively, return string

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, tostring, inorder

I have a toString method, which should return a string representing the whole binary search tree in order. I've come this far, but this is just printing out the numbers in order, and the toString method just returns the value of rootNode of course. I don't know how I should solve this.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    if (rootNode == null){
        return "";
    }
    else {
        return inorder(rootNode.data);
    }
}

/** 
 * @param root
 */
public String inorder(Node<T> root){
    if (root != null){
        inorder(root.left);
        System.out.println(root.value + " ");
        inorder(root.right);
    }
}
```

I've been stuck with this problem for hours.

Comment: what is the problem? your description matches with the code. what are you expecting from `toString()` function? If possible provide the full code and sample input/output for your program.

Comment: No, the toString method should **return** the whole BST as one string, not just print it out.

Comment: Problem is, in void inorder(Node<T>), he is not interested in printing, rather generating a String sequence inside the method inorder(Node<T>), So, after call to String s = inorder(Node<T>), s would print the tree in inorder structure and inorder(Node<T>) would need to return String if he is interested in sending the result back from toString() method

Comment: Right now the `inorder` method ***prints*** each node as it visits it.  If you want to ***return*** the entire tree you have to return a string value (i.e. not void) and add the subtree to the current node value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{
    java.lang.StringBuilder toReturn = new java.lang.StringBuilder();  
    if (rootNode == null){
        return "";
    }
    else{
        inorder(rootNode.data , toReturn);
    }
    return toReturn.toString();
}

/** 
 * @param root
 */
public void inorder(Node<T> root , java.lang.StringBuilder treeLikeStringBuilder){
    if (root != null){
        inorder(root.left);
        System.out.println(root.value + " ");
        treeLikeStringBuilder.append( root.value.toString() + " " );
        inorder(root.right);
    }
}
```

inorder(Node , StringBuilder) signature would instead help in building a String like structure for the inorder traversal, so that toString() could return that String inorder travsersal, also StringBuilder is used so that the changes made to the MUTABLE StringBuilder passed as argument (StringBuilder toReturn) to method inorder(Node , StringBuilder) would reflect the changes back in the toString() method, hope it helps??

Answer (score -1):

The below algorithm simplifies your task, all it does is visit every node with respect to inOrder algorithm and append that node data to the string.

```
public void inOrder(Node<T> root, string NodeData){ // Algorithm for inOrder - "left child node, root, right child node"
    if (root != null){
        inOrder(root.left, NodeData);  // traverse left sub tree
        NodeData += root.Data.ToString() + "  |  "; // append to NodeData
        inOrder(root.right, NodeData); // traverse right sub tree
    }
}
```

invoke the method like this:

```
string TreeNodeData = "";
Tree.inOrder(ENTER ROOT OF TREE HERE, TreeNodeData);
```

Finally, you can check the result with:

```
System.out.println(TreeNodeData);
```

Comment: This is wrong, you cannot pass NodeData by reference in Java. It doesn't carry new value through multiple calls.